# Multiple backend call with Retrofit at same time

Tags: android, retrofit

I' using Retorfit for one my Android project and I just realized this cool library, doesn`t make any call in parallel, but once by one. I always staring a new Thread or an AsyncTaks for my backend calls (obviously), but Retrofit put all of my request into a Queue (I think) and processing them after each other.

Re-implement the backend side is not a solution for now, does anyone know how can I force retrofit to take 3-4 request at the same time ?

Thank you,

Comment: Calling it with a `loop` strategy can solve your problem

Comment: may I kindly ask you to explain it more ? I fireing asynctasks in a listview adapter, but I think Retrofit catch them and put in a queue!